# How to print the right hemisphere of a square matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to print the right hemisphere of a matrix. If we draw the main and the secondary diagonals in a matrix we see that we got 4 equal parts, the right part is called (in my algorithms textbook) the right hemisphere of a square matrix.

For example, in the following `5 x 5` matrix, the right hemisphere is made of the elements: `-1, -3, -2, 0`.

[image]

The way I have tried to solve this problem is by starting and composing half of the secondary diagonal and then print each element on the right of the element on the left diagonal. After I reach the middle of the secondary diagonal I repeat this process on the lower part of the main diagonal.

Something like that (at least, this is how I see it in my head):
[image]

Here is some working code that prints the right hemisphere of a `5 x 5` matrix. It works, but it is ugly and it doesn't work properly of matrices that have even number of lines and columns, for example a `4 x 4` matrix.

```
#include <iostream>

#define N 5
#define M 5

void printHemisphere(int matrix[N][M], int n, int m)
{
    int i = 1;
    for(int j = n - 1; j > n / 2; i++, j--)
    {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < m; ++k)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[i][k] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    for(int j = n / 2; j < n; i++, j++)
    {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < m; ++k)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[i][k] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
     int matrix5[N][M] = 
     {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
        {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
        {16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
        {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}
     };


    printHemisphere(matrix5, N, M);

    return 0;
}
```

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Is this supposed to support non-square matrices? If so, how?

Comment: No, it should work only on square matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for square matrices:

```
void printHemisphere(int matrix[N][M], int n, int m)
{
    int mid = n / 2;
    for(int i = 1; i < mid; i++)
    {
        for (int j = n - i; j < m; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    for(int i = mid; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < m; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The outer loops skip the first and last rows because no output can come from them.

Comment: This solution has the same problem as marom's. If you try it you will see the output is only `12`, whereas it should be `8 12`. The solution: for `j` you should use `n-1` instead of `n`. Thus, j starts at `(n-1)-i+1` = `n-i`. Moreover, the top lines are in the range [0, (N/2) -1], and the bottom ones are in [N/2, N-1]. So, the first loop could be `for(int i = 1; i < mid; i++)` and the second one `for(int i = mid; i < n - 1; i++)`. You can check it at https://ideone.com/PzJOAN

Comment: @FabioTurati - Thanks for testing this (which I should have done before posting--shame on me). I've updated my code to fix the problems (including eliminating the bogus `k` subscript).

Comment: Guys, thank you very much for helping me with this problem. I have to admit that the solution was not that obvious for me, and I had to struggle a little bit to understand it (in the real sense). Did you applied some pattern for solving this kind of problems, or it's just about intuition (that gets developed by practice)?

Comment: @cristid9 - I've dealt with this kind of problem before, so I applied experience. (Plus, as is evident in the comments, some trial-and-error.) I wouldn't glorify it as a "pattern" because it isn't formalized or structured, and I wouldn't call it "intuition" because one does have to think about these things. The trick in this case (if you can call it that) is to first decide to process the matrix by row and then to recognize that the condition for what row elements to output changes where the diagonals cross. Your own diagrams actually show most of that work already done.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to get out with just a double for loop:

```
void printHemisphere(int matrix[N][M], int n, int m)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < n - 1 ; i++)
    {
        for (j = max(i, n - i) ; j < m ; j++)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[i][k] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In general I like this answer, but there are a couple of things you could improve: 1) You are printing `matrix[i][k]`, you meant `matrix[i][j]` 2) `i` starts from 1 and stops at `n-2`, but in a matrix indices go from 0 to `n-1`. It means you are optimizing the code, knowing that the first and last line can be skipped. Fine, but I'd write it as a comment 3) The reason that `j` starts at `max(i, n-i)` could be explained in a comment. I know that `i` is the coordinate of the main diagonal at line `i` and `n-i` of the other one, and max basically gives the rightmost, but you could explain that.

Comment: The code outputs wrong results for a `4 x 4` matrix: https://ideone.com/N9ElqS. It should print just `8` and `12`.

Comment: The inner loop should start at `max(i, n - i) + 1`, not `max(i, n - i)`. OP doesn't want the on-diagonal elements.

Comment: @TedHopp you are right, this approach would also include on-diagonal elements. But actually it would still be wrong. the correct formula is `(int j = std::max(i, n - 1 - i) + 1;`. I was also wrong in my previous comment: at line `i`, the element of the secondary diagonal is at `n-1-i`, not at `n-i`. So while the general idea behind this approach is right, the code requires some tuning.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-code... :

```
for row in 1 -> height - 2 // Indices between 0 -> height - 1
   distance = min(row, height - 1 - row)
   for cell in (width - distance) -> width - 1
      print matrix[row][cell]
```

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of `distance = min(row, height - 1 - row)`? I am not sure if I got it. It seems like `distance`  is equal to the number of elements that should be printed, is that right?

Comment: @cristid9 - it "measures" the distance from the closest "edge row" (either the first, top row - or the last, bottom row). For each row further away from the edge, you need to print 1 more horizontal cell...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it. I am coming a little late, as you have already accepted a solution; still, I would like to show you some things. For example, that if you treat these matrices as monodimensional arrays you can test matrices of all sizes with just one function, because the size doesn't have to be "built into" the data type in your function definition. And I have commented it a lot, hoping to make it as clear as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


// I store matrices as a monodimensional array, so that it is easier to deal
// with matrices of different sizes in the same program, because you can do
// everything with one function. Moreover, I use only one argument here, to make
// it clear that we are dealing with square matrices.
void printHemisphere(int* matrix, int last_row)
{
    int last_column = last_row; // It's a square matrix, so they are the same.
                                // Still, distinguishing between last_column
                                // and last_row can make the algorithm clearer,
                                // so I have kept both

    // In general I prefer to use "row" and "column" as variable names, instead
    // of "i" and "j"

    // Our rows go from 0 to last_row-1, but since the first and last one can
    // certainly not be used, we can skip them: we start at row = 1, and we stop
    // at last_row - 2 (that is, the last one for which row < last_row - 1)
    for(int row = 1; row < last_row - 1 ; row++)
    {
        // We want to start from the cell to the right of the rightmost diagonal.
        // The main diagonal has column = row;
        // The secondary diagonal has column = last_row - 1 - row
        // The rightmost one is the maximum of these 2.
        // Then, we want to take the cell to the right of the diagonal, so we
        // have to add 1 more.
        // All in all we have:
        for (int column = std::max(row, last_row - 1 - row) + 1;
             column < last_column;
             column++)
        {
            // since this is a 1-D array we have to access it this way
            std::cout << matrix[row*last_row+column] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // Since I am working with monodimensional arrays, I don't store them as
    // int matrix3[3][3], but rather as int matrix3[9], which I have expressed as
    // int matrix3[3*3] for clarity.
    //For each one I have indicated the expected output.

    // Expected output:
    // 6
    int matrix3[3*3] = 
    {
        1, 2, 3,
        4, 5, 6,
        7, 8, 9
    };

    // Expected output:
    // 8
    // 12
    int matrix4[4*4] = 
    {
        1, 2, 3, 4,
        5, 6, 7, 8,
        9, 10, 11, 12,
        13, 14, 15, 16
    };

    // Expected output:
    //    10
    // 14 15
    //    20
    int matrix5[5*5] = {
         1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
         6,  7,  8,  9, 10,
        11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
        16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23, 24, 25
    };

    // Expected output:
    //    12
    // 17 18
    // 23 24
    //    30 
    int matrix6[6*6] = {
         1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,
         7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12,
        13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
        19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
        25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
        31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36
    };

    // Expected output:
    //       14
    //    20 21
    // 26 27 28
    //    34 35
    //       42
    int matrix7[7*7] = {
         1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
         8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
        22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,
        29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
        36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
        43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49
    };


    printHemisphere(matrix3, 3);
    printHemisphere(matrix4, 4);
    printHemisphere(matrix5, 5);
    printHemisphere(matrix6, 6);
    printHemisphere(matrix7, 7);

    return 0;
}
```

I have verified it on ideone and it works. The only thing I would like to add is: to make sure the code works, make sure you test it with an odd-sized and with an even-sized matrix.